# Unable to narrow down why getting wrong timestamp via stat

Tags: c, pointers, memory, pass-by-reference

So I am trying to code something for office work which involves getting timestamp for last time the file was updated to compare if the file got changed or not. I have literally broken my head over it for 2 days and moments away from giving it up. Would be huge huge help if someone can help.

/* starter, a code runs and stores a file's time stamp in old_var variable */

```
int bar (const char* path,time_t *time)
{
      struct stat s;
  
      if (stat(path, &s)) {
          return 1;
      }

      *time = s.st_mtime;
      return 0;
}

static int
foo_update (const char* path, time_t * foo_time)
{
    bar(path, foo_time);
//printing foo_time here gives correct value.
    return 0;
}

/* one long parent function calls foo_update*/

time_t var;
bzero(&var,sizeof(time_t));
foo_update(path,&var);
//printing var value here gives wrong (older val).
```

/* post this, we compare the var value with old_var to see if the its 2nd time we are parsing something or not.
when we do memcmp of var and old_var, it does not come 0.

I have even tried printing time_t val by converting to struct tm type. Then I saw
when I am trying to print var value, it comes as old val in this func, whereas it comes as new val when printing it in foo_update. This is very surprising as old_var is not being used anywhere in this func.
I am passing by reference. Not sure what is missing.

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: Hi @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica. No. None at-all. Its live code. I was supposed to edit something around it and hit this by chance and now I am supposed to fix this :(

Comment: What does "old val" mean?   There's no updating going on in the code fragment,  so it's difficult to know what is meant.

Comment: This `bzero(var,sizeof(time_t))`probably needs `&var`, though I don't see it as contributing.

Comment: Hi @user16632363,
So basically we are storing this val in some local structure. And once we get new value, we try and compare it with old val to see if it got changed. Let me update question with that detail.

Comment: Hi @Shawn,
That was a copying mistake, i have updated the question.

Comment: Should probably distill it down to a [mcve], not a few fragments of code.

Comment: Formulating a MRE is a great debugging technique in its own right, with the added bonus that if preparing it does not reveal the error to you then the resulting MRE will probably reveal it to us.

Comment: @deepakchaurasiacoen The code you posted worked perfectly for me when I fleshed it out just enough to compile and run it.  So your problem must be in something we can't see.